# How can i reload my page withou losing my chart inside a canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have the following code:

```
   <div id='info_e1' style="display: inline_block" ></div>
   <script>
       (function($){
           $(document).ready(function(){        
               var $container = $("#info_e1");

               $container.load('getinfo.php');
               var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
                   var $ctx = $("#canvas-e1")[0].getContext('2d');
                   console.log($ctx);
                   $container.load('getinfo.php');
                   $('#chart-e1').append($ctx);
               }, 5000);
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

So, `getinfo.php` returns a table with data from a sql query in database. 
In my php code the canvas element is inserted:

```
echo " <td rowspan='10'>

<div>
   <div id='chart-e1'>  
      <canvas id='canvas-e1' ></canvas> 
   </div>
</div>

</td>";
```

Let's say I have a chart drawn in the canvas element, the problem is that after 5 seconds when the div is reloaded my is also deleted. Is there anyway to save the content from the canvas and to add it back to the canvas on reload?

Comment: Why don't you just pout your canvas outside of the refreshed div?

Answer (score 0):

Don't reload your chart at all. Or use local storage to store the results `getinfo.php`for later reuse.

[Here](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage) you can check whether your targeted browser support local storage or not.

Comment: Also add a fallback to cookies for older browsers

Comment: Actually forget my comment. You are using canvas.